# String Cutting with multiple lines

Tags: python, string, csv, cut

so i'm new to python besides some experience with tKintner (some GUI experiments).

I read an .mbox file and copy the plain/text in a string. This text contains a registering form. So a Stefan, living in Maple Street, London working for the Company "MultiVendor XXVideos" has registered with an email for a subscription.

```
Name_OF_Person: Stefan
Adress_HOME: London, Maple
    Street
 45
Company_NAME: MultiVendor
XXVideos
```

I would like to take this data and put in a .csv row with column 
  "Name", "Adress", "Company",...

Now i tried to cut and slice everything. For debugging i use "print"(IDE = KATE/KDE + terminal... :-D ). 
  Problem is, that the data contains multiple lines after keywords but i only get the first line.

### How would you improve my code?

```
import mailbox
import csv
import email
from time import sleep
import string
fieldnames = ["ID","Subject","Name", "Adress", "Company"]
searchKeys = [ 'Name_OF_Person','Adress_HOME','Company_NAME']
mbox_file = "REG.mbox"
export_file_name = "test.csv"

if __name__ == "__main__":
 with open(export_file_name,"w") as csvfile:
 writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, dialect='excel',fieldnames=fieldnames)
 writer.writeheader()

 for message in mailbox.mbox(mbox_file):
   if message.is_multipart():
     content = '\n'.join(part.get_payload() for part in message.get_payload())
     content = content.split('<')[0] # only want text/plain.. Ill split #right before HTML starts
     #print content
   else:
     content = message.get_payload()
   idea = message['message-id']
   sub =  message['subject']
   fr = message['from']
   date = message['date']
   writer.writerow ('ID':idea,......) # CSV writing will work fine

   for line in content.splitlines():
     line = line.strip()
      for pose in searchKeys: 
       if pose in line: 
         tmp = line.split(pose)
         pmt = tmp[1].split(":")[1]
         if next in line !=: 
         print pose +"\t"+pmt
       sleep(1)
csvfile.closed
```

OUTPUT:

```
OFFICIAL_POSTAL_ADDRESS  =20
```

Here, the lines are missing.. 
from file:

```
OFFICIAL_POSTAL_ADDRESS: =20
London, testarossa street 41
```

EDIT2:

@Yaniv
Thank you, iam still trying to understand every step, but just wanted to give a comment. I like the idea to work with the list/matrix/vector "key_value_pairs"

The amount of keywords in the emails is ~20 words. Additionally, my values are sometimes line broken by "=". 
I was thinking something like:

```
Search text for Keyword A, 
if true: 
 search text from Keyword A until keyword B 
 if true:
  copy text after A until B

Name_OF_=
Person: Stefan
Adress_
=HOME: London, Maple
Street
 45
Company_NAME: MultiVendor
XXVideos
```

Maybe the HTML from EMAIL.mbox is easier to process?

```
<tr><td bgcolor=3D"#eeeeee"><font face=3D"Verdana" size=3D"1">
<strong>NAM=
 E_REGISTERING_PERSON</strong></font></td><td bgcolor=3D"#eeeeee"><font    
 fac=e=3D"Verdana" size=3D"1">Stefan&nbsp;</font></td></tr>
```

But the "=" are still there 
should i replace ["="," = "]  with "" ?

Comment: Do you know for sure that the order is always the same 1) `Name_OF_Person:`, 2) `Adress_HOME:` , 3) `Company_NAME:` ?

Comment: It is a html reg form on our website and i have to take the reg forms from the past 10 years (x~10000 mails) and create a csv with all data. The form changed once, unless that it's always the same. EDIT: 

  But there are like 25 entries before that and after that with different line numbers each time

Comment: Explain different line numbers? Meaning there are different numbers of lines for each header? Just getting clarifying questions before a propose solution

Comment: `if next in line !=:` can't possibly be right. please only paste code that actually can run.

Comment: @hop yepp true.. .

Comment: @matisetorm in my mbox file are X-thousand emails. I have 25 Keywords to look for and write it in csv. Linenumbers was the wrong word.

Comment: All good. :) I solved for the problem as specified. If that is the case, regex or the proposed solution by Yaniv is the best bet

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the "EDIT2" part, and the issue with those "=" characters. If you want to trim some annoying characters (like whitespaces, or "="), use strip() or rstrip() etc.; these can get a list of characters to strip.    As for the eventual formatting of your final result: Maybe consider a 2-step process here: (1) Parse input files with as few assumptions as possible (see my answer here for example); then (2) Review the results manually, possibly in aggregate manner, analyze for problems with the assumptions. Modify code of (1). Go to (1). Repeat until happy. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would go for a "routine" parsing loop over the input lines, and maintain a `current_key` and `current_value` variables, as a *value* for a certain *key* in your data might be "annoying", and spread across multiple lines.

I've demonstrated such parsing approach in the code below, with some assumptions regarding your problem. For example, if an input line starts with a whitespace, I assumed it must be the case of such "annoying" value (spread across multiple lines). Such lines would be concatenated into a single value, using some configurable string (the parameter `join_lines_using_this`). Another assumption is that you might want to strip whitespaces from both keys and values.

Feel free to adapt the code to fit your assumptions on the input, and raise Exceptions whenever they don't hold!

```python
# Note the usage of .strip() in some places, to strip away whitespaces. I assumed you might want that.
def parse_funky_text(text, join_lines_using_this=" "):

    key_value_pairs = []

    current_key, current_value = None, ""
    for line in text.splitlines():
        line_split = line.split(':')
        if line.startswith(" ") or len(line_split) == 1:
            if current_key is None:
                raise ValueError("Failed to parse this line, not sure which key it belongs to: %s" % line)
            current_value += join_lines_using_this + line.strip()
        else:
            if current_key is not None:
                key_value_pairs.append((current_key, current_value))
                current_key, current_value = None, ""
            current_key = line_split[0].strip()
            # We've just found a new key, so here you might want to perform additional checks,
            # e.g. if current_key not in sharedKeys: raise ValueError("Encountered a weird key?! %s in line: %s" % (current_key, line))
            current_value = ':'.join(line_split[1:]).strip()

    # Don't forget the last parsed key, value
    if current_key is not None:
        key_value_pairs.append((current_key, current_value))

    return key_value_pairs
```

Example usage:

```
text = """Name_OF_Person: Stefan
Adress_HOME: London, Maple
    Street
 45
Company_NAME: MultiVendor
XXVideos"""

parse_funky_text(text)
```

Will output:

```
[('Name_OF_Person', 'Stefan'), ('Adress_HOME', 'London, Maple Street 45'), ('Company_NAME', 'MultiVendor XXVideos')]
```

Comment: Although, I do like this suggestion as well :)

Answer (score -1):

You indicate in the comments that your input strings from the content should be relatively consistent. If that is the case, and you want to be able to split that string across multiple lines, the easiest thing to do would be to replace `\n` with spaces and then just parse the single string.

I've intentionally constrained my answer to using just string methods rather than inventing a huge function to do this. Reason: 1) Your process is already complex enough, and 2) your question really boils down to how to process the string data across multiple lines. If that is the case, and the pattern is consistent, this will get this one off job done

`content = content.replace('\n', ' ')`

Then you can split on each of the boundries in your consistently structured headers.

```
content = content.split("Name_OF_Person:")[1] #take second element of the list
person = content.split("Adress_HOME:")[0] # take content before "Adress Home"
content = content.split("Adress_HOME:")[1]  #take second element of the list
address = content.split("Company_NAME:")[0] # take content before 
company = content.split("Adress_HOME:")[1]  #take second element of the list (the remainder) which is company
```

Normally, I would suggest regex. (https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html). Long term, if you need to do this sort of thing again, regex is going to pay dividends on time spend munging data. To make a regex function "cut" across multiple lines, you would use the `re.MULTILINE` option. So it might endup looking something like `re.search('Name_OF_Person:(.*)Adress_HOME:', html_reg_form, re.MULTILINE)`

Comment: They are very powerful. (if not a bit confusing at times, but the basic patterns will get you very far). Don't forget to accept answer if I helped :)

Comment: yea i think i have to create a mix between the 2 answers from you and @yaniv